# iOS DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) .. Error : No ad to show

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, google-dfp

I am using DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) in my App. I have integrated it as per [DOCs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals#ios) as follows.

```
 dfpBannerView_ = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
 dfpBannerView_.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
// Set the delegate to listen for GADBannerViewDelegate events.
dfpBannerView_.delegate = self;

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
dfpBannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:dfpBannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[dfpBannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

where kSampleAdUnitID is the App Unit Id I have created.

following Delegate Method is getcalled

```
- (void)adView:(DFPBannerView *)view
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
NSLog(@"%d",error.code);
}
```

But still I gets error as follows,

```
Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show.
2014-04-11 17:40:55.836 DFPBannerExample[6319:70b] 1
```

Where error Code 1 stands for `/// The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned.
  kGADErrorNoFill,`

I am not getting where is the problem. Why I am not getting Ads ,while I am getting Ads for Sample App Unit Id .

Comment: hi, did you solved the problem?

Comment: Hello @R.Dewi , Yes. Actually problem was, I had not created the Ad Unit Ids properly. If they are created properly, then we can see the Ads :)

Comment: can you tell me how to get Ad Unit ID? @mohan

Comment: @R.Dewi .. http://www.google.co.in/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/ Login with gmail. or you can also use the AdMode Account. AdMobe is easy to integrate.

Comment: what is the different between http://www.google.co.in/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/ and google admob?

Comment: @R.Dewi .. Just Google it .. But Google Ad Mob SDK is easy to integrate

Answer (score 0):

if you want your banner to display something, you need to specify the banner size, and then tag the banner with the adunit id: check this code:

```
 bannerView_ = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(111, 483, 537, 120)];

bannerView_.adUnitID = @"/5900406/UserAppWaitingView";

// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
```

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

```
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
```

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

Comment: Thanks For the reply @lvan Felipe Garcia . But the Very first Line " dfpBannerView_ = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];" , kGADAdSizeBanner is Actually a size . :)